# calculate age in years and months and melt data

Tags: r, time

I'm working with some time data and I'm having problems converting a time difference to years and months.

My data looks more or less like this,

```
dfn <- data.frame(
Today  = Sys.time(),
DOB  = seq(as.POSIXct('2007-03-27 00:00:01'), len= 26, by="3 day"),
Patient  = factor(1:26, labels = LETTERS))
```

First I subtract the data of birth (`DOB`) form today's data (`Today`).

```
dfn$ageToday <-  dfn$Today - dfn$DOB
```

This gives me the `Time difference in days`.

```
dfn$ageToday
 Time differences in days
  [1] 1875.866 1872.866 1869.866 1866.866 1863.866
  [6] 1860.866 1857.866 1854.866 1851.866 1848.866
 [11] 1845.866 1842.866 1839.866 1836.866 1833.866
 [16] 1830.866 1827.866 1824.866 1821.866 1818.866
 [21] 1815.866 1812.866 1809.866 1806.866 1803.866
 [26] 1800.866
 attr(,"tzone")
 [1] ""
```

This is where first part of my question comes in; **how do I convert this difference to years and months (rounded to months)?** (i.e. 4.7, 4.11, etc.)

I read the `?difftime` man page and the `?format`, but I did not figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Furthermore, I would like to melt my final object and if I try using melt on the data frame above using this command,

```
require(plyr)
require(reshape)
mdfn <- melt(dfn, id=c('Patient'))
```

I get this strange warning I haven't see before

```
Error in as.POSIXct.default(value) : 
  do not know how to convert 'value' to class "POSIXct"
```

So, my second question is; **how do I create a time diffrence I can `melt` alongside my `POSIXct` variables?** If I melt without `dfn$ageToday` everything works like a charm.

Thanks, Eric

Answer (score 5):

The `lubridate`package makes working with dates and times, including finding time differences, really easy.

```
library("lubridate")
library("reshape2")

dfn <- data.frame(
    Today  = Sys.time(),
    DOB  = seq(as.POSIXct('2007-03-27 00:00:01'), len= 26, by="3 day"),
    Patient  = factor(1:26, labels = LETTERS))

dfn$diff <- new_interval(dfn$DOB, dfn$Today) / duration(num = 1, units = "years")

mdfn <- melt(dfn, id=c('Patient'))
class(mdfn$value) # all values are coerced into numeric
```

The `new_interval()` function calculates the time difference between two dates. Note that there is a function `today()` that could substitute for your use of `Sys.time`. Finally note the `duration()` function that creates a standard, ehm, duration that you can use to divide the interval by a length of standard units, in this case, a unit of one year.

In case you want to preserve the contents of `Today` and `DOB`, then you may want to convert everything to `character` first and reconvert later...

```
library("lubridate")
library("reshape2")

dfn <- data.frame(
  Today  = Sys.time(),
  DOB  = seq(as.POSIXct('2007-03-27 00:00:01'), len= 26, by="3 day"),
  Patient  = factor(1:26, labels = LETTERS))

# Create standard durations for a year and a month
one.year <- duration(num = 1, units = "years")
one.month <- duration(num = 1, units = "months")

# Calculate the difference in years as float and integer
dfn$diff.years <- new_interval(dfn$DOB, dfn$Today) / one.year
dfn$years <- floor( new_interval(dfn$DOB, dfn$Today) / one.year )

# Calculate the modulo for number of months
dfn$diff.months <- round( new_interval(dfn$DOB, dfn$Today) / one.month )
dfn$months <- dfn$diff.months %% 12

# Paste the years and months together
# I am not using the decimal point so as not to imply this is
# a numeric representation of the diference
dfn$y.m <- paste(dfn$years, dfn$months, sep = '|')

# convert Today and DOB to character so as to preserve them in melting
dfn$Today <- as.character(dfn$Today)
dfn$DOB <- as.character(dfn$DOB)

# melt using string representation of difference between the two dates
dfn2 <- dfn[,c("Today", "DOB", "Patient", "y.m")]
mdfn2 <- melt(dfn2, id=c('Patient'))

# alternative melt using numeric representation of difference in years
dfn3 <- dfn[,c("Today", "DOB", "Patient", "diff.years")]
mdfn3 <- melt(dfn3, id=c('Patient'))
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. It's almost there, though it does not round the age to months. It shows ages as 2.96 years, I would like that  to be 3 years, nothing after the decimal point should be bigger then .11 (if that makes sense?)

Comment: @eric-d-brean -- I have extended my second code snippet to give you a couple of ways to approximate to your target... It should be easy to go from here to what you intend. I give you a couple of alternatives.